# Django filter OrderingFilter default choice

Tags: python, django, django-filters

I have created an ordering filter with django filters and I have been wondering how I can set the default choice and remove the empty choice.

```
class MyFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    name = django_filters.CharFilter(lookup_expr='icontains')

    o = django_filters.OrderingFilter(
        choices=(
            ("created", _("Created, old to new")),
            ("-created", _("Created, new to old"))
        ),
        fields = (
            "created", "created"
        )
    )
```

When I render the filter form the empty choice "----" is being shown as default. I would like to set one the of filtering choices as default and remove the empty choice.

Comment: What if you set `required=True` for the `OrderingFilter`?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem required=True did not remove the empty label, only required that an option must be selected. Solution was to disable empty_label and null_label. See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

The fix was to disable the empty option by setting the empty_label and null_label to None. This was the first option is the default option. Note, the first option should algin with the default ordering of your queryset so that it matches when loading the page without using a filter.

```
class MyFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    name = django_filters.CharFilter(lookup_expr='icontains')

    o = django_filters.OrderingFilter(
        choices=(
            ('created', _('Created, old to new')),
            ('-created', _('Created, new to old'))
        ),
        fields = (
            'created', 'created'
        ),
        empty_label = None,
        null_label = None
    )
```